# Is it possible to reproduce the behavior of the "tag" attribute in local notifications?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), the "tag" attribute can:

> If specified and a notification with the same tag is already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one in the notification drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is the [`NotificationManager.notify()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification)) that has the `tag` parameter:

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same tag and id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

But even if you don't use the one with `tag`, simply notifying the NotifsManager with a notification with the same `id` would replace it:

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Comment: I figured that passing the "tag" by itself would already replace the notification, but if the id is different it has no effect whatsoever. I thought it best to use the second approach and use the "id" to replace the notification. Thanks @al